# How to access Heroku app console by heroku CLI

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I can check logs by `heroku logs --app=my_app_name` . I want to access app's console as shown in the picture. How can I access by heroku cli?

[image]

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am managed to access my app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To access Heroku app bash by CLI:-

```
heroku login
heroku ps:exec --app=scoreboard-backend-dev
```

scoreboard-backend-dev is the app name